# How to take value from html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, url, parameters

```
    $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
success: function(msg){
alert(msg);
  }
data: "html"
});
```

after this, a html should be returned. But how can you fill textbox from a html file.
So, for example

if the html contains following part:

```
    <tr><td class="tabelrow">Name:</td><td class="data">software</td></tr>
```

a textbox should be filled with the word software.

I hope this is a bit clear.

Comment: do you have any server-side code?

Comment: Then that's what you need, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want something like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  success: function(msg){
    alert($(html).find(".data").text());
  }
  data: "html"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#textBoxId').val($(html).find(".data").text());
```